# sh: Is it safe to use a variable as a command if the command contains only letters, number and underscores?

Tags: shell, dash-shell

I'm writing a POSIX compliant script in dash so I am having to get creative with using fake arrays.

Contents of fake_array.sh

```
fake_array_job() {
array="$1"
job_name="$2"

comma_count="$(echo "$array" | grep -o -F ',' | wc -l)"

if [ "$comma_count" -lt '1' ]; then
    echo 'You gave a fake array to fake_array_job that does not contain at least one comma. Exiting...'
    exit
fi

array_count="$(( comma_count + 1 ))"

position=1
while [ "$position" -le "$array_count" ]; do
    item="$(echo "$array" | cut -d ',' -f "$position")"

    "$job_name" || exit

    position="$(( position + 1 ))"
done
}
```

Contents of script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

. fake_array.sh

job_to_do() {
    echo "$item"
}
fake_array_job 'goat,pig,sheep' 'job_to_do'

second_job() {
    echo "$item"
}
fake_array_job 'apple,orange' 'second_job'
```

I am aware that it may seem silly to use a unique name for each job I pass to fake_array_job, but I like that I have to type it twice because it helps to reduce human error.

I keep reading that it is a bad idea to use a variable as a command. Does my use of "$job_name" to run a function have any negative implications as it concerns stability, security or efficiency?

Comment: Do you know the value of `IFS`, or can that potentially be changed by code outside your library?

Comment: BTW, `source` itself is a bashism, so your code already won't work with a baseline-POSIX `/bin/sh`.

Comment: `grep -o` [isn't portable either](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html).

Comment: I am pretty new to scripting. Does the value of IFS need to be set in a script or is it a global constant?

Comment: There's a default (which splits only on newlines, tabs and spaces).

Comment: Anyhow -- since you're *quoting* `"$job_name"`, your code is much less unsafe than it could be (if it were being expanded unquoted); the value of IFS doesn't actually make a difference with the quotes in place, since your string is parsed as only containing the name of a single command to run with no arguments. If that's what you want, you're on pretty solid ground.

Comment: `fake_array_job () { cmd=$1; shift; for arg; "$cmd" "$arg"; done; }` with `job_to_do () { echo "$1"; }` and `second_job () { echo "$1"; }` seems far simpler; use it as `fake_array_job job_to_do goat pig sheep`. There's nothing wrong with storing the *name* of a command in a variable, just not a command and its arbitrary arguments.

Comment: I echoed IFS into a file and opened it in vim; it it seems to contain a space, a tab, and two newlines; actually I forget that echo adds a newlines...

Comment: @HaroldFischer The second newline comes from `echo` itself, not the value of `IFS`.

Comment: The second newline presumably came from `echo`. Generally speaking, echo can't be trusted not to modify what you're using it to inspect; safer to `printf '%s' "$IFS" | od`, or such; see the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html

Comment: @chepner I do take your meaning, but the purpose of this is to be able to iterate through a fake array, the echo "$item" bit was just for the purpose of demonstration

Comment: `while [ -n "$var" ]; do case $var in *,*) next=${var%%,*}; var=${var#*,}; "$cmd" "$next";; *) "$cmd" "$var"; break;; esac; done` -- much more efficient to do the string manipulation internal to the shell and not involve `cut`.

Comment: @Charles Duffy Did not realize that about the -o option for grep. Will have to find another way to count the commas. I'm kind of surprised shellcheck missed that, it's done a pretty good job of making me more POSIX-aware

Comment: shellcheck's good about telling you when you're using non-POSIX syntax for the shell itself with a #!/bin/sh shebang, but it doesn't check non-shell utilities' usage for extensions (since someone could intentionally write a script for /bin/sh but have it depend on GNU-only tools).

Comment: @Charles Duffy Any chance you know of a tool that checks for GNUisms?

Comment: @HaroldFischer Not a code-checking tool, but http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html provides links to the specification for each standard tool. If you're using a tool, stick to what's documented there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Read to the end for a good suggestion by Charles Duffy. I'm too lazy to completely rewrite my answer to mention it earlier...)

---

You can iterate over the "array" using simple parameter expansions without requiring multiple elements in the array.

```
fake_array_job() {
    args=${1%,},   # Ensure the array ends with a comma
    job_name=$2

    while [ -n "$args" ]; do
        item=${args%%,*}
        "$job_name" || exit
        args=${args#*,}
    done 
}
```

One problem with the above is that assures that the array is comma-terminated by assuming that `foo,bar,` is not a comma-delimited array with an empty last element. A better (though uglier) solution is to use `read` to break up the array.

```
fake_array_job () {
  args=$1
  job_name=$2
  rest=$args
  while [ -n "$rest" ]; do
    IFS=, read -r item rest <<EOF
$rest
EOF
    "$job_name" || exit
  done  
}
```

(You can use `<<-EOF` and make sure the here doc is indented with *tabs*, but it's hard to convey that here, so I'll just leave the ugly version.)

There's also Charles Duffy's good suggestion of using `case` to pattern match on the array to see if there are any commas left or not:

```
while [ -n "$args" ]; do
  case $var in 
    *,*) next=${args%%,*}; var=${args#*,}; "$cmd" "$next";;
      *) "$cmd" "$var"; break;; 
  esac;
done
```

Comment: I missed Charles Duffy's similar comment while typing this up.

Comment: I *do* think your suggestion of making it `"$job_name" "$item"` (in the comments) was wise; that's a clearer calling convention, not relying on global variables being passed around.

Comment: Yeah, for the answer I'm just sticking to making the comma-delimited string simpler to work with.

Comment: I must be doing something stupid because I keep getting trapped in a loop when I give the function 'kitten,meow,purr' as the first argument

Comment: No, that's my fault. My code assumes that each element in the array is *terminated* by a comma, rather than *separated* by commas. This means in the end, when `$args == purr`, that `args=${args#*,}` won't match and `$args` stays `purr` forever.

Comment: Use `IFS=, read head tail` would not have the problem, but I want to avoid the here document it requires for aesthetic purposes. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: The `case` approach to check for a comma used in my comment would also work around that issue. :)

Comment: When using the case $var in ... esac, is it OK to put $var in double quotes?

Comment: Yes; I tend to leave things unquoted when not strictly required.